# In JAXB Marshalling , how to identify which child element caused JAXB Marshalling Exception?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, jaxb2

I am getting this exception when marhsalling my JAXBElement, which has several child elements. How do I figure out how to pinpoint which child element caused this exception ?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.AttributeProperty.getIdValue(AttributeProperty.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.getId(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$IDREFTransducedAccessorImpl.print(TransducedAccessor.java:290)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$IDREFTransducedAccessorImpl.print(TransducedAccessor.java:271)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.AttributeProperty.serializeAttributes(AttributeProperty.java:101)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeAttributes(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:375)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:689)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:358)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:358)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:69)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:172)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:358)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:161)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:333)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:76)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleReferenceNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleReferenceNodeProperty.java:115)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:358)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:358)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:158)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:358)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:69)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:172)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:159)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:358)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:156)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:333)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:340)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:76)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:251)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:75)
    at com.tdsecurities.fxdev.doddfranktdmladapter.SwapTDMLGeneratorJunitTest.testHello(SwapTDMLGeneratorJunitTest.java:113)
```

This is the code that I use to marshall the Jaxbelment:

JAXBElementdmlJAXBElement=  SwapDMLGenerator.generateDML(event, leg1ordMm,leg2ordMm,
                                                                                 leg1OrdCs, leg2OrdCs);

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext_m = JAXBContext.newInstance(DmlWrapper.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext_m.createMarshaller();
//marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "");
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);        
String  outFileName= String.format("dml-%d-ordm_deallnum-%s.xml",System.currentTimeMillis(), .getDealNumber());
File fout= new File(destDir, outFileName);
FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(fout);
marshaller.marshal(dmlJAXBElement, fos);
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way that I can think of is include the source code of JAXB in the project, run the program in the debug mode and put a conditional break point in eclipse. 
See [How to set a conditional break point in eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint?)
The condition would be that the attribute is null, since you are getting NPE.
Then when the execution stops at that point you can inspect the appropriate variable.

Other alternative would be to see if increasing the log level gives you any more information.

Comment: That did not work. The exception happens inside the marshaller.marshal and it does not   output the defective element name. And enhancing the log settings to debug level also doe not work as aparently the marshaller code does not output debug logs.

Comment: What I was saying is you step into the marshal method while debugging. For that to work you'll need the source code added to the project. [example] (http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-view-and-debug-jdk-source-code-in-eclipse.html?page=1)

Answer (score 0):

using Eclipse IDE, it is possible to debug some 3rd party code, like Sun's JAXB implementation.

In Eclipse, try these two blocks:

Enabling 3rd party debug support

```
Search for class AttributeProperty inside your classpath entry for JRE System Library
In Outline tab, expand class file and respective class inside this
Right-Click on target method (in this case: AttributeProperty.getIdValue)
Click on: Toggle Method Breakpoint
```

Check which fields are with problem:

1. Enable Debug Tab and Variables Tab
2. Like in other debug processes, start your tests in debug mode
3. When program achieve related breakpoint, check on Variables Tab 'this' and 'arg0' references. These references contains information about current node and mashalled object

In this point, you have the context ready to analyse and debug it.

I'm dealing with same JAXB/IDREF issue and don't have any solution, yet. I'm checking on it.

Did you solved this problem?

Best Regards,

And Past